# Como redesenhar uma janela com PyQT5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt-5

Tenho um CRUD feito com PyQT5 que adiciona um usuário para um banco de dados **PostgreSQL** e faz uma buscar para mostrar os usuários cadastrados em um **QT ListWidget**.

Porém, ao adicionar um novo usuário, a tela não "recarrega" sendo necessário reiniciar o programa para que o usuário adicionado apareça na lista.

Segue prints demonstrando o problema.
Assim que adiciono o usuário **Teste 2**:

[image: Assim que adiciona um usuário novo]

Mas, só ao reiniciar o programa, **Teste 2** aparece na lista:

[image: Imagem do programa reiniciado]

Já tentei utilizar os comandos:

```
widget.update()
widget.repaint()
widget.redraw()
```

Mas, mesmo assim, sem sucesso.

Alguma ideia de como eu poderia dar um refresh no widget sem ter que reiniciar o aplicativo?

Código que busca e adiciona usuários à lista:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM dados")
busca = c.fetchall()
for row in busca:
    itm = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(row[1])
    self.listWidget.addItem(itm)
```

Código que adiciona um usuário ao banco de dados:

```
def clica_adicionar(self):

    nome = self.txt_nome_add.text()
    matricula = self.txt_matricula_add.text()
    cargo = self.txt_cargo_add.text()
    email = self.txt_email_add.text()

    c.execute("INSERT INTO dados (nome, matricula, cargo, email, cliente, relatorio, data) VALUES "
              "(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
              (nome, matricula, cargo, email, cliente, rela, data))
```

Comment: Caro Guilherme, crie um exemplo simples da falha e poste o código, provavelmente o problema não é redesenhar e sim como os eventos estão correndo paralelamente (isto se estiverem paralelos, porque se não for o caso provavelmente ai esta a falha).

Comment: Adicionei os códigos de inserção no banco de dados e de busca para exibir na lista. Mas, acredito não ser o problema visto que o programa funciona. O problema está em toda vez ter que reiniciar o programa para atualizar a lista. De toda forma, grato pelo aviso.

Comment: Caro Guilherme, aonde esta o evento do CONNECT para detectar os clicks? Ao invés de postar o código real, cria uma versão bem simplificada que cause o erro e posta o código aqui, quanto menor, melhor :)

Comment: Entendi! Vou tentar, assim que der, fazer um exemplo mais simples. Mas respondendo: O único connect nesse caso está no botão adicionar do primeiro print. self.btn.clicked.connect(self.clica_adicionar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui atualizar o Widget e resolvi responder aqui para ajudar quem estiver com o mesmo problema.

Sempre que um novo item for adicionado, basta chamar a função `refresh` depois da ação.

No modelo:

```
def clica_adicionar(self):
  nome = self.txt_nome_add.text()
  matricula = self.txt_matricula_add.text()
  cargo = self.txt_cargo_add.text()
  email = self.txt_email_add.text()

  c.execute("INSERT INTO dados (nome, matricula, cargo, email, cliente,   relatorio, data) VALUES "
          "(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
          (nome, matricula, cargo, email, cliente, rela, data))

  widget.refresh()
```

Comment: Este método é nativo do `QWidget`?